# Cloud-init not executing vRA cloud-config script?

Tags: vmware, ubuntu-server, cloud-init

I'm trying to deploy a VM from vRealize Automation 8.2 from an Ubuntu Server 20 image I've created. I've configured it in order to use OVF datasource but during initialization I get this message at the /var/log/cloud-init-output.log after it configures some ssh keys.

```
Cloud-init v. 20.3-2-g371b392c-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 running 'modules:config' at Thu, 22 Oct 2020 11:10:48 +0000. Up 54.17 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 20.3-2-g371b392c-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 running 'modules:final' at Thu, 22 Oct 2020 11:10:51 +0000. Up 57.52 seconds.
ci-info: no authorized SSH keys fingerprints found for user cloudadmin.
Cloud-init v. 20.3-2-g371b392c-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 finished at Thu, 22 Oct 2020 11:10:52 +0000. Datasource DataSourceNone.  Up 58.65 seconds
2020-10-22 11:10:52,919 - cc_final_message.py[WARNING]: Used fallback datasource
```

As result, cloud-init doesn't execute any of the commands I specify in the Blueprint, so any user is created and packages are installed. The only configuration I've applied to the VM before creating the image was "dpkg-reconfigure cloud-init" and selected the OVF option. The /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/90_dpkg.cfg is as follows

```
# to update this file, run dpkg-reconfigure cloud-init
datasource_list: [ OVF ]
```

Answer (score 2):

See `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-installer.cfg` in ubuntu  it overrides some parameters including `datasource_list`

Comment: Dude/Dudette - just wow! I have been banging my head against the wall for the past 14 hours. I guess these configs are created during the installation? 99-installer.cfg indeed sets the datasource_list: [None]. THANK YOU!

Comment: So how did you solve it ? I am having a similar problem where datasource is being set to None: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75507635/not-able-to-run-a-user-script-on-some-ec2-instances-started-from-an-ami-of-ubunt